# Has the 50 move rule been used in serious games?

Tags: master-games, 50-move-rule

There are a lot of questions about the 50-move rule; details on how to claim the draw, why the number 50, etc...

But the most interesting question seems to be whether the rule has ever been applied in an actual game! (N.B. I am referring to serious sanctioned games only). To be more concrete:

> Is there any official game between FIDE masters or above which ended in a draw as a result of one of the players invoking the 50-move rule?

Comment: There are some recognizable names [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifty-move_rule).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, many times. [Ivanchuk- Kamsky 2009](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1554423) is one example, but there are hundreds if not thousands of others. [Ushenina - Girya 2013](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1716505) made some news recently because Ushenina couldn't mate with knight and bishop in time.

Comment: If you know of any notable games which reached a position where the shortest forced mate-in-N following the last capture or pawn promotion would take more than 50 moves, and where the side with advantage ended up in a mate with N minus 50, that would be very interesting to add.  I wonder what the largest "N" for any competitive game to date would be?